# way of changing a circular mesh on top of a gltf

Tags: three.js, geometry, mesh, react-three-fiber, gltf

Does anyone know how to make this yellow circular mesh to have the same geometry as the shirt, in a way that the shirt is covered by it.

My current code does this:

[image: what i have now (shirt with circular mesh)]

Im using raycaster to move the mesh to always stay on top of the shirt but i dont know how i can make it "bend".

I want it to look like this:

[image: expected final result]
[image: other angle]

```
        //shirt = gltf model
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var intersects;
        var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3();
        var worldNormal = new THREE.Vector3();
        var lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3();
        var dragging = false;
        //events
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
        window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp, false);

        function onMouseDown(event) {
            let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([cube]);
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                controls.enableRotate = false;
                dragging = true;
            }
        }

        function onMouseUp(event) {
            controls.enableRotate = true;
            dragging = false;
        }

        function onMouseMove(event) {
            mouse.set((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
            intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([shirt.scene.children[0]]);

            if (intersects.length == 0 || !dragging) return;

            normalMatrix.getNormalMatrix(intersects[0].object.matrixWorld);
            worldNormal.copy(intersects[0].face.normal).applyMatrix3(normalMatrix).normalize();
            cube.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
            cube.lookAt(lookAtVector.copy(intersects[0].point).add(worldNormal));
            cube.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        }
```

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=deca#webgl_decals

Answer (score 0):

You need decals for this purpose. If you understand and use react you could use [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-platform-ioxywi?file=/src/Canvas.js) example.